# Realizar consulta INSERT INTO con SELECT DISTINCT con datos de 2 tablas

Tags: sql

Necesito insertar valores en una tabla mediante consulta SQL que seleccione los distintos `id_cliente` que existen en la tabla `Clientes` con su importe y el resto de campos de la tabla `Facturas` sumando **1** al campo `num_factura` (es el número de factura del cliente en sí).

La idea es realizar esto cada mes para generar las facturas mensuales de los clientes y quiero que se almacenen en la tabla Facturas.

Estas son las tablas y sus respectivos campos:

---

**Facturas**

- id_factura (Key)
- id_cliente
- num_factura
- fecha_factura
- importe

---

**Clientes**

- id_cliente (key)
- precio_total

---

El campo `id_factura` es un campo único y autoincrementable.

El campo `id_cliente` puede repetirse para cada `num_factura` distinto.

El campo fecha_factura la facilito yo cada mes.

He probado esto y me duplica todos los valores de la tabla `Facturas`:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT Clientes.Id_cliente, Facturas.num_factura + 1, Facturas.fecha_factura, 
Clientes.precio_total
FROM Clientes 
INNER JOIN Facturas ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente
WHERE Clientes.Id_cliente IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id_cliente FROM Clientes);
```

Cuando realizo la consulta por primera vez lo ejecuta correctamente pero a la siguiente vez que la ejecuto vuelve a repetir todo lo que existía en la tabla Facturas y además lo nuevo también, pasando de 100 registros, a 200, 400 ,800, etcétera.

¿Cómo puede solucionarse esta situación?

Ejemplo de lo que ocurre al ejecutar:

**Tabla Original Facturas:**

```
id_factura   id_cliente  num_factura  fecha_factura  importe
         1           10         001     31/08/2016    105€
         2           11          001     31/08/2016     95€
```

**Tabla Facturas después de la primera ejecución del INSERT**

```
id_factura   id_cliente  num_factura  fecha_factura  importe
         1           10          001     31/08/2016    105€
         2           11          001     31/08/2016     95€
         3           10          002     31/08/2016    105€
         4           11          002     31/08/2016     95€
```

**Tabla Facturas después de segunda ejecución del INSERT**

```
id_factura   id_cliente  num_factura  fecha_factura  importe
         1           10          001     31/08/2016    105€
         2           11          001     31/08/2016     95€
         3           10          002     31/08/2016    105€
         4           11          002     31/08/2016     95€
         5           10          002     31/08/2016    105€
         6           11          002     31/08/2016     95€
         7           10          003     31/08/2016    105€
         8           11          003     31/08/2016     95€
```

**Lo que quieroquiero obtener tras la segunda consulta...:**

```
    id_factura   id_cliente  num_factura  fecha_factura  importe
             1           10          001     31/08/2016    105€
             2           11          001     31/08/2016     95€
             3           10          002     31/08/2016    105€
             4           11          002     31/08/2016     95€
             5           10          003     31/08/2016    105€
             6           11          003     31/08/2016     95€
```

Comment: A ver si entendí. El mismo id_cliente puede estar mas de una vez insertado en la tabla resultante? Y lo que quieres es que cuando se inserte un id_cliente que ya estaba, sume 1 al num_factura. Es eso lo que quieres? Pero si es eso, no entiendo bien, porque solo hay 2 clientes y 2 faturas en tu ejemplo, entonces no se por que quieres 4 registros como resultado?

Comment: Oh ya entendi, es que estas insertando dentro de la misma tabla Facturas, pensé que era en otra.

Answer (score 4):

Intenta con esto:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT c.id_cliente,
(
  SELECT max(num_factura) + 1 from facturas
  WHERE id_cliente = c.id_cliente
) as num_factura, -- obtiene el ultimo numero de factura por cliente y le suma 1
current_date as fecha_factura,
c.precio_total
FROM Clientes c;
```

Sólo modifica el current_date por la fecha que le corresponda a la factura.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba usando una tabla temporal:

```
SELECT 
 Clientes.Id_cliente, 
 Facturas.num_factura + 1, 
 Facturas.fecha_factura, 
 Clientes.precio_total
INTO #temp
FROM Facturas 
INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente

INSERT INTO Facturas 
( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT 
 Id_cliente, 
 num_factura, 
 fecha_factura, 
 precio_total
FROM #temp
```

Comment: Nop, esta consulta hace lo mismo que le hace la del el.

Comment: No había entendido que era la misma tabla, modifiqué la solución con el uso de tablas temporales.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución que a mi me funcionó es ejecutando tu misma consulta pero insertando los datos en otra tabla que contenga exactamente los mismos campos que la tabla Facturas.

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas_copy ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT Clientes.Id_cliente, Facturas.num_factura + 1, Facturas.fecha_factura, 
Clientes.precio_total
FROM Clientes 
INNER JOIN Facturas ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente
WHERE Clientes.Id_cliente IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id_cliente FROM Clientes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sigo sin poder comentar vuestras respuestas por falta de puntos.

Al final la respuesta que me ha solucionado el problema es la de @Dan y sólo he tenido que modificar el current_date por la entrada de datos de mi formulario para introducir la fecha_factura.

Enlace a la respuesta válida de @Dan : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20260/12686

Os dejo el código final para ayuda de otros.

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT c.id_cliente, (SELECT max(num_factura) + 1 from facturas
  WHERE id_cliente = c.id_cliente
) AS num_factura, ([Formularios]![Fecha Facturación]![fecha_facturas]) AS fecha_factura, c.precio_total
FROM Clientes AS c;
```

[Fecha Facturación] = Nombre del Formulario.

[fecha_facturas]= Nombre del cuadro de texto donde introducimos la fecha para la que queremos generar las facturas de los clientes.

Gracias a todo el mundo.

Comment: Genial que pudiste solucionarlo. Solo resta comentar que las queries anidadas son desaconsejadas en general, ya que la forma en que son tratadas por el motor, puede generar mucha carga en momentos en que el sistema sea grande. Por ejemplo, si tienes 1000 facturas, se correran por lo bajo 2000 queries. Ahora, depende bastante de tus datos, si el crecimiento esperado es bajo (en un año solo generarás 5000 facturas) no es un problema del cual preocuparse

Comment: Entiendo que si puedes, comentar tu pregunta y editarla para aclarar.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT Clientes.Id_cliente, MAX(Facturas.num_factura) + 1, Facturas.fecha_factura, Clientes.precio_total
FROM Clientes 
INNER JOIN Facturas ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente
GROUP BY Facturas.Id_cliente;
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, tu quieres insertar una factura por cada cliente, utilizando la información de fecha y número de una factura anterior al mismo cliente.

Para ese caso, la solución es esta:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT   Clientes.Id_cliente
       , max(Facturas.num_factura) + 1
       , max(Facturas.fecha_factura)
       , Clientes.precio_total
  FROM Clientes 
       INNER JOIN Facturas ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente;
```

Claro que, acá, si ingresas un nuevo cliente, que no tiene ninguna factura, **no** se creara una nueva factura para él. En el caso que **si** quieras crear facturas para los nuevos clientes, debes utilizar esta otra versión del script y proporcionar un valor por defecto para el número de factura y la fecha, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Facturas ( id_cliente, num_factura, fecha_factura, importe )
SELECT   Clientes.Id_cliente
       , coalesce(max(Facturas.num_factura) + 1, 1)
       , coalesce(max(Facturas.fecha_factura), '2016-08-01')
       , Clientes.precio_total
  FROM Clientes 
       INNER JOIN Facturas ON Clientes.Id_cliente = Facturas.id_cliente;
```

Dado que no indicas el motor que utilizas, he utilizado la constante de fecha en formato ISO, pero eso no es bien recibido por todos los motores, y en ocasiones dependerá de la configuración local (del cliente, o del servidor) para su correcto funcionamiento. Ya es tarea tuya adaptarlo para que funcione con el motor de tu predilección.